# Dynamically change jquery .css image with matching image in stylesheet

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to dynamically change the following jquery code's css image with one that matches in the stylesheet.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".trigger-wrapper").click(function () {
    $("#menu-wrapper-left").stop().animate({width: 'toggle'});
    $('#hero-container').css('image1.jpg)');
    return false;
});
});
```

Pay attention to this line below.

```
$('#hero-container').css('image1.jpg)');
```

How can I dynamically change this to match the numbered image in the stylesheet?

The images in the stylesheet are stored like so.

```
.hero li:nth-child(1) span { 
  background-image: url('http://image1.jpg');
}
.hero li:nth-child(2) span { 
  background-image: url('http://image2.jpg');
}
.hero li:nth-child(3) span { 
  background-image: url('http://image3.jpg');
}
```

Here's the html just incase.

```
<div id="hero-container" class="swipe slide">
  <ul class="hero transparent">
    <li><span>Image 01</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
    <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use ({'background-image':'img.png'}) ?

edit:

try:

```
var a = 1; // set n child
var bgUrl $(".hero li:nth-child("+a+") span").css("background-image"); // get bg img
$("#hero-container").css({"background-image":bgUrl}); // set bg img
```

You might need to tinker some.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: How do I do that? I'm still fairly new to jquery.